# GeoJSON vs. Maptiler Layer mismatch after initialization

Tags: leaflet, geojson, maptiler

my LeafLet map contains a GeoJSON and a Maptiler layer.
First I set up my map by `var map = L.map(...)`. Right after that I add my GeoJSON layer. Then I load my map style via AJAX, change a few things in it, and finally add it to the map as well.

After the map is initialized, both layers seem to have a mismatch in zoom and pan (see image).

[image: GeoJSON - Maptiler mismatch]

Comment: You're gonna need to show some code. Please take a bit of time to read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks, @IvanSanchez - I know it was quite little of information, sorry for that. I'll consider your advice in future.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that the Mapbox-GL-LeafLet-plugin (https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-leaflet) which is advised by Maptiler, is not working for me.

When I use an open, unstyled TileLayer, the problem is gone.